Merging some FFMPEG code into AutoHotKey
I'm using some ready-made AutoHotKey that calls upon FFMPEG. I need to tweak what FFMPEG does, but I'm just so lost, so would really appreciate some help.
It currently does some simple FFMPEG scaling (amongst other things, all working fine). Ultimately, I need to replace the simple scaling with something that also shifts the video down, leaving empty space at the top. I'm open to all suggestions here, but:
I've found some code that uses the Overlay filter that I'm trying to adapt. But I can't work it into the AutoHotKey, and I'm not 100% sure my edits are valid.
The code I'm trying to integrate is (with my tweaks):
nullsrc=size=562x1000 [base];

[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=562x500 [upper];

[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=562x500 [lower];

[base][upper] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1];

[tmp1][lower] overlay=shortest=1:x=0:y=501

Source: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos
I think/hope I've set it to render the same input video twice: once at the top, and once at the bottom. If I can skip the top copy and leave the nullsrc empty there, then even better I suppose, I was just concerned this might trip up the code.
Finally, this is the AutoHotKey I'm currently running.
; video_postprocess_boomerang.ahk - an AutoHotKey script to postprocess a video after
;   capture in DSLR Remote Pro to create a boomerang video
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; This script can rotate, resize and add an overlay and soundtrack to a video
; captured using DSLR Remote Pro v3.11.3 onwards. It uses ffmpeg to modify the
; video.
;
; Usage: set the "Delay before playback" to 30 seconds in the video booth
; settings in DSLR Remote Pro and then double click on this script to run it.
;
; Command line usage to process a single video by reading the XML summary file:
; Open a command prompt window, cd to the folder containing this
; script and then run ot with the pathname of the video booth XML summary file
; e.g. video_postprocess.ahk C:\Users\chris\Documents\PhotoboothImages\2018-10-31\IMG_0001.xml
;
; Add an optional overlay by placing a PNG file named video_overlay.png in the photo booth images folder
; Add an optional soundtrack by placing an audio file named video_soundtrack.mp3 or video_soundtrack.wav
; in the photo booth images folder
; Add an optional 'intro' video at the start by placing a video file named video_intro.mp4 in the photo booth images folder
; Add an optional 'outro' video to the end by placing a video file named video_outro.mp4 in the photo booth images folder
; IMPORTANT: the video_intro.mp4 and video_outro.mp4 files must be the same size as the output video otherwise the script won't work
;
; Edit this script to change the following variables:
; copyFolder - the name of the subfolder in which to save a copy of the original video
; boomerang - set this to 1 to create forwards/backwards boomerang or set to 0 to create forwards only video
; rotateDegreesClockwise - optional rotation in 90 degree intervals
; videoHeight - height of the video (after rotation). Set this to 0 to disable resizing
; videoPreset - ffmpeg preset for video CODEC. Set to veryslow, slow, fast, veryfast or ultrafast
; cropWidth - optional cropping of video in pixels
; loops - the number of times to loop the boomerang video
; playbackSpeed - speed up or slow down the video
;
; FFmpeg can be downloaded from https://www.ffmpeg.org/
;
; AutoHotKey is free and can be downloaded from:
; http://www.autohotkey.com
;
; This script comes with no warranty or support whatsoever and may be freely
; copied or modified as required.
;
; Written by Chris Breeze, www.breezesys.com
; 20181112: Initial version based on the original video_postprocess.ahk script
; 20181126: Added optional video_intro.mp4
; 20190405: Added bomerang option
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#singleinstance force
SetTitleMatchMode,2
StringCaseSense, Off

; subfolder in which to save a copy of the original video
copyFolder := "originals"

; boomerang: set this to 1 to play the video forwards then backwards or 0 to play forwards only
boomerang := 1

; rotate video in 90 degree increments, valid values: 0, 90, 180, 270
rotateDegreesClockwise := 0

; height of the video (after rotation). Set this to 0 to disable resizing
videoHeight := 600

; Crop the video to this width (after rotation). Set this to 0 to disable cropping
cropWidth := 0

; the number of times to loop the video
loops := 3

; video playback speed
playbackSpeed := 2

; ffmpeg video preset, choose from: veryslow, slow, fast, veryfast and ultrafast
videoPreset := "veryfast"

; set this to 1 to display debug info (0 to disable debug)
showDebugMessages := 0

;----------- Please don't change anything below here unless you know what you're doing! ----------------

; make sure videoHeight is an even number
if Mod(videoHeight, 2)
{
    videoHeight++
}

ffmpeg = %A_ScriptDir%\ffmpeg.exe
ifNotExist,%ffmpeg%
{
    MsgBox ERROR: ffmpeg.exe not found.`nPlease make sure ffmpeg.exe is in the same folder as this script:`n%A_ScriptDir%
    exitapp
}

if showDebugMessages
{
    ; display a debug window at the top of the screen
    Gui +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow  ; +ToolWindow avoids a taskbar button and an alt-tab menu item.
    Gui, Color, cBlack
    Gui, Font, s12 
    Gui, Add, Text, vStatusText cLime, AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    Gui, Add, Text, vStatusText2 cLime, AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    Gui, Show,x100 y0 NoActivate,%A_ScriptName%  ; NoActivate avoids deactivating the currently active window.
    GuiControl,,StatusText,Please wait...
    GuiControl,,StatusText2,
}

; look for XML file in the command line
if %0%
{
    path = %1%
    SplitPath, path,,, ext
    if (ext = "mp4")
    {
        video = %1%
        screenDir := "."
    }
    else if (ext = "xml")
    {
        IfNotExist, %1%
        {
            MsgBox ERROR: XML file not found: %1% 
            exitapp
        }
        ; read XML file, process video and exit
        FileRead, Contents, %1%
        RegExMatch(Contents, "<video_information>", video) 
        RegExMatch(Contents, "<photobooth_images_folder>(.*)</photobooth_images_folder>", photoboothFolder) 
        RegExMatch(Contents, "<download_folder>(.*)</download_folder>", downloadFolder) 
        RegExMatch(Contents, "<video_file>(.*)</video_file>", file) 

        if not Contents contains <video_information>
        {
            MsgBox ERROR: not a video booth summary file: %1%
            exitapp
        }
        if photoboothFolder < 1
        {
            MsgBox ERROR: video booth summary file doesn't contain <photobooth_images_folder> tag
            exitapp
        }
        if downloadFolder < 1
        {
            MsgBox ERROR: video booth summary file doesn't contain <download_folder> tag
            exitapp
        }
        if file < 1
        {
            MsgBox ERROR: video booth summary file doesn't contain <video_file> tag
            exitapp
        }

        screenDir = %photoboothFolder1%
        video = %downloadFolder1%\%file1%
    }
    else
    {
        MsgBox XML or MP4 image not found 
        exitapp
    }

    IfNotExist, %video%
    {
        MsgBox ERROR: video file not found: %video% 
        exitapp
    }
    IfNotExist, %screenDir%
    {
        ;MsgBox ERROR: Screen folder not found: %screenDir% 
        ;exitapp
    }
    showDebugMessages = 1
    ProcessVideo(video, screenDir)
    exitapp
}

; loop waiting for video files to process
DebugMessage(1,"Window title")
Loop
{
    IfWinExist, Breeze Systems Photobooth - 
    {
        WinGetTitle, Title, Breeze Systems Photobooth - 
        if title contains video_processing
        {
            RegExMatch(title, "\s-\s(.*)", screen) 
            SplitPath, screen1, screenFilename, screenDir
            DebugMessage(1, "Screen folder: " screenDir)
            ControlGetText, msg, Static2, Breeze Systems Photobooth
            RegExMatch(msg, ",\s*movie=(.*)", video) 
            IfExist, %video1%
            {
                ProcessVideo(video1, screenDir)

                ; tell photo booth the processed video is ready
                WinActivate, Breeze Systems Photobooth -
                Send ^z
                DebugMessage(2, "Sending Ctrl+Z to photo booth...")
                Sleep 1000
            }
            else
            {
                DebugMessage(2, "Waiting for movie to download...")
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DebugMessage(1, Title)
            DebugMessage(2, "Waiting for video_processing screen...")
        }
    }
    else
    {
        IfWinExist, DSLR Remote Pro for Windows -
        {
            DebugMessage(1, "Not running in photo booth mode")
        }
        else
        {
            DebugMessage(1, "DSLR Remote Pro is not running")
        }
        DebugMessage(2, "")
    }
    Sleep 100   ; sleep for 1/10th sec to avoid hogging the processor
}

ProcessVideo(video, screenFolder)
{
    global ffmpeg, copyFolder, videoHeight, rotateDegreesClockwise
    global videoPreset, showDebugMessages
    global boomerang, playbackSpeed, cropWidth, loops

    DebugMessage(2, "Processing " video)

    rotate :=
    if rotateDegreesClockwise = 90
    {
        rotate := "transpose=1"
    }
    else if rotateDegreesClockwise = 180
    {
        rotate := "transpose=2,transpose=2"
    }
    else if rotateDegreesClockwise = 270
    {
        rotate := "transpose=2"
    }

    overlay = %screenFolder%\video_overlay.png
    intro = %screenFolder%\video_intro.mp4
    outro = %screenFolder%\video_outro.mp4

    audio = %screenFolder%\video_soundtrack.mp3
    IfNotExist,%audio%
    {
        audio = %screenFolder%\video_soundtrack.wav
    }

    ; make a copy of the original video and delete any temp files
    SplitPath,video,name,folder
    videoCopyFolder = %folder%\%copyFolder%
    FileCreateDir,%videoCopyFolder%
    videoCopy = %videoCopyFolder%\%name%
    videoTemp = %videoCopyFolder%\temp_%name%
    videoTempReversed = %videoCopyFolder%\temp_reversed_%name%
    videoProcessed = %videoCopyFolder%\processed_%name%
    FileDelete,%videoCopy%
    FileDelete,%videoTemp%
    FileDelete,%videoTempReversed%
    FileDelete,%videoProcessed%
    FileCopy,%video%,%videoCopy%

    ; First pass: speed up, crop, rotate, scale, add overlay and drop audio
    inputFiles = -i "%video%"
    filter :=
    if playbackSpeed <> 1
    {
        speed := 1 / playbackSpeed
        filter = setpts=%speed%*PTS
    }
    if cropWidth
    {
        if filter
        {
            filter = %filter%,crop=%cropWidth%
        }
        else
        {
            filter = crop=%cropWidth%
        }
    }
    if rotate
    {
        if filter
        {
            filter = %filter%,%rotate%
        }
        else
        {
            filter = %rotate%
        }
    }
    if videoHeight > 0
    {
        if filter
        {


            filter = %filter%,scale=-2:%videoHeight%

        }
        else
        {
            filter = scale=-2:%videoHeight%
        }
    }
    if filter
    {
        filter = [0:v]%filter%
    }
    else
    {
        filter = [0:v]copy
    }
    IfExist,%overlay%
    {
        inputFiles = %inputFiles% -i "%overlay%"
        filter = %filter%[bg],[bg][1:v]overlay=0:0
    }
    cmd = "%ffmpeg%" -y %inputFiles% -filter_complex "%filter%" -c:v libx264 -preset %videoPreset% -an "%videoTemp%"
    runwait,%cmd%,,Hide
    ; FileAppend,%cmd%,test.bat
    ; MsgBox 1) %cmd%

    if boomerang
    {
        ; Second pass: create reversed copy
        cmd = "%ffmpeg%" -y -i "%videoTemp%" -vf reverse "%videoTempReversed%"
        runwait,%cmd%,,Hide
        ; FileAppend,%cmd%,test.bat
        ; MsgBox 2) %cmd%
    }

    ; Third pass: join them together with optional intro and outro videos
    if loops < 1
    {
        loops := 1
    }
    numInputs := 0
    inputFiles :=

    filter :=
    IfExist,%intro%
    {
        inputFiles = %inputFiles% -i "%intro%"
        filter = %filter%[%numInputs%:v:0]
        numInputs := numInputs + 1
    }
    Loop, %loops%
    {
        inputFiles = %inputFiles% -i "%videoTemp%"
        filter = %filter%[%numInputs%:v:0]
        numInputs := numInputs + 1
        if boomerang
        {
            inputFiles = %inputFiles% -i "%videoTempReversed%"
            filter = %filter%[%numInputs%:v:0]
            numInputs := numInputs + 1
        }
    }
    IfExist,%outro%
    {
        inputFiles = %inputFiles% -i "%outro%"
        filter = %filter%[%numInputs%:v:0]
        numInputs := numInputs + 1
    }
    IfExist,%audio%
    {
        inputFiles = %inputFiles% -i "%audio%"
        filter = %filter% concat=n=%numInputs%:v=1:a=0 [v]
        mapAndCodec = -map "[v]" -map %numInputs%:a -c:v libx264 -preset %videoPreset% -shortest
    }
    else
    {
        filter = %filter% concat=n=%numInputs%:v=1 [v]
        mapAndCodec = -map "[v]" -preset %videoPreset% -c:v libx264 
    }
    cmd = "%ffmpeg%" -y %inputFiles% -filter_complex "%filter%" %mapAndCodec% "%videoProcessed%"
    runwait,%cmd%,,Hide
    ; FileAppend,%cmd%,test.bat
    ; MsgBox 3) %cmd%

    ; delete temporary files and overwrite original with processed video
    FileDelete, %videoTemp%
    FileDelete,%videoTempReversed%
    FileMove,%videoProcessed%,%video%,1
}

; Display a debug message if showDebugMessages = 1
; num specifies the line on which to display the message (1 or 2)
; msg is the message to display
DebugMessage(num, msg)
{
    global cStatusText, cStatusText2
    global showDebugMessages
    msg := A_Hour ":" A_Min ":" A_Sec ": " msg
    if showDebugMessages
    {
        if num=1
        {
            GuiControl,,StatusText,%msg%
        }
        else
        {
            GuiControl,,StatusText2,%msg%
        }
    }
}

GuiClose:
ExitApp


And within that, this is the line of code I think it should replace:
        {

            filter = %filter%,scale=-2:%videoHeight%

        }

I'd appreciate some help so much, I'm tearing my hair out! Thanks for reading.
J
